# Strange PWA/Manifest Behavior on iOS

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am just beginning to dip my toes into the PWA waters and have started by playing with the manifest.json on a site I am building. My goal is to get it to open up in fullscreen.

I am getting some very strange behavior on iOS.

I add the PWA to the home screen fine and it correctly uses the short name as specified by the manifest. But when I try to open it things go off the rails. The app seems to attempt to load in fullscreen per the manifest but then stops and the website instead opens in a new Safari tab, twice. I have two new tabs both pointing to the URL of the PWA.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is not too late for you.

I had the same problem and I realize it is course by `manifest link tag` in the  `header`:

```
<link id="manifest_link" rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

The moment you have this, any link or redirect from your PWA will launch Safari regardless of internal or external link.

One solution is to have the link remove from header  with `javascript` after you load the file:

```
var manifestlink = document.getElementById("manifest_link"); 
document.head.removeChild(manifestlink);
```

However that might course some issues for `android`. You have to test your scenario with on both thoroughly.